# How does Windows know to set daylight savings time even though PC is not connected to Internet?

Tags: windows

I have a PC that hasn't been connected to Internet for years and did not have any Windows Updates for years as well, so how does PC know to set clock forward/backward 1 hour? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean summer time?

Comment: sntp points to time.windows.com

Comment: yes, but don't use due there is no internet connection, it uses it own clock, summer/winter time is defined in regional settings.

Comment: scroll down till: Windows time zone registry information https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914387

Comment: ok, basically it's programmed in registry to know for many years ahead when to change DST.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia: most of the United States and Canada observe DST from the second Sunday in March to the first Sunday in November.

Similar rules are in place in Europe. When you set up your Windows PC, you tell it where you live, and it calculates Daylight Savings based on the date. Regardless of whether or not you're connected to the internet, the first Sunday in November is always the First Sunday in November.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no internet connection, Windows uses PC internal clock to maintain the system date time.

The registry keys used for DST are:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
```

Take a deep look in MSDN: [How to configure the daylight saving time settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914387)

There is a tool called [Tzedit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914387#bookmark-m2) that you can download from Microsoft.